# Universal $C^*$ algebra subject to $ x^*x+y^*y=xx^*+yy^*$

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

What is the precise description for the universal unital $C^*$ algebra generated by two elements $x,y$ subject to relation $$ 
x^*x+y^*y=xx^*+yy^*$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't exist. A requirement to have a universal C$^*$-algebra in terms of generators is that the relations give a bound for the norm of the generators. That's not the case here, as given any $x,y$ as you want you can replace them with $nx$ and $ny$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$ and still keep the relation.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. BTW is there a simple  $C^*$ alfebra with this property?

Comment: Of course: $C^*_r(\mathbb F_2)$, for instance.